# What will the service name of crontab in a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task, crontrigger

I have a `crontab` in the same name `crontab`. Need to check whether its running currently or not.

Its placed in **/etc/crontab** in a Linux machine.

I guess its service name is `crond`. So I tried `grep crond`.

If its wrong please confirm me?

How can I check it?

Comment: Depends on your distribution, but `crond` is not a bad guess. But finally you will have to either read the documentation or check the file contents of the cron package installed. Also a look at the daemons startup script should be helpful.

Comment: Actually I just see in my system that it is just `/usr/sbin/cron`. Grepping for "cron" is better anyway when you don't know the exact name: `ps aux|grep cron`

Comment: I think this might be a version specific question. In my case, I have `/usr/bin/crontab` which is the `crontab` executable, `/usr/sbin/cron` which is the `cron` executable and `/etc/init.d/cron` which is the service since `ps aux | grep cron` returns a process named `cron`. What OS/version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
/usr/sbin/service cron status
```

You could get something like that:

```
user@server:~$ /usr/sbin/service cron status
[ ok ] cron is running.
```